# Replacing indices in Awk array while keeping the order of values unchanged

Tags: awk

I can't figure how to keep array value order unchanged while sorting it with `asort`. I know that sorting by definition changes the order, but why it still does so with `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@unsorted"`? I have two arrays, in which the consecutive values are paired (so that the n-th value of array `b` is paired with the n-th value of array `b_sorted`. But the starting indices are different, so I want to changes them by assigning consecutive ordinals to values in each array (let's assume I don't need the original indices anymore, but the order of values still matters). My goal is to be able to get every n-th pair of elements from the arrays.

In the toy example below, `b` and `sorted_b` are the arrays in question.

```
echo 5TOMATO3CUCUMBER4ORANGE | gawk '{

n = patsplit($0, a, /[0-9]/, seps)
PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@unsorted"
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {b[a[i]] = seps[i]; print b[a[i]], a[i]}
asort(b, sorted_b)
for (i in sorted_b)
    {print sorted_b[i], i}
  
}'
```

I get:

```
TOMATO 5
CUCUMBER 3
ORANGE 4
CUCUMBER 1
ORANGE 2
TOMATO 3
```

But I want:

```
TOMATO 5
CUCUMBER 3
ORANGE 4
TOMATO 1
CUCUMBER 2
ORANGE 3
```

**Edit: After some comments, I realized my question was indeed unclear. I came up with this example to better explain what is my point.**

```
  echo 5TOMATO3CUCUMBER4ORANGE | gawk '{

    n = patsplit($0, a, /[0-9]/, seps)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        sum+=a[i]
        arr[sum]=seps[i]
    }

for (i in arr)
    {print arr[i], "index", i}

asort(arr, sorted_arr)

for (i in sorted_arr)
    {print sorted_arr[i], "index", i}
}
```

This is the output:

```
TOMATO index 5
CUCUMBER index 8
ORANGE index 12

CUCUMBER index 1
ORANGE index 2
TOMATO index 3
```

However, I would like the last 3 lines (after `asort`) to look like this (i.e. having the same order of values in the resulting array):

```
   TOMATO index 1
   CUCUMBER index 2
   ORANGE index 3
```

Comment: I can't imagine what you're trying to do. You apparently want to sort the array but not change the array and have the values sorted in it retain the order they had before you sorted it. Makes absolutely no sense to me. Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: I agree that was a poor explanation, I expanded and rephrased it.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense so I added an answer based on what you say in the question you want to try to help us get to what it is you really need.

Comment: I just want to change the indices to `1,2,3` keeping the order of values unchanged. Why is that unclear?

Comment: it's unclear because the indices of both arrays are **already** `1,2,3` (so what do you mean when you say you want to change them to `1,2,3`?) and the values **have no order**, they're just values stored in memory that can be looked up by their indices (so what do you mean when you say keeping the order of the values unchanged?). I updated my answer, see the bottom and let us know if that's what you're trying to do - if so, I can't imagine why you'd want to do that.

Comment: Your point is valid, my example was poorly chosen. I have changed it in the edit now.

Comment: I still dont get it. Where does the order TOMATO, ORANGE, CUCUMBER come from? It's not the input order, it's not the sorted order, it's not the order of the indices anywhere before or after `sort` so what logic decides TOMATO should get index 1, ORANGE 2, and CUCUMBER 3? You say `having the same order of values in the resulting array` but that order isn't the same as anything as far as I can see - not numeric indices, not alphabetical values - nothing.

Comment: I **think** your ```arr``` assignment should be ```arr[a[i]]=seps[i]``` and your ```sort``` should be ```asort(arr, sorted_arr, "@val_str_desc")```

Comment: Thanks @gersh99. To be precise, I was looking for `asort (arr, sorted_arr, "@unsorted")`, but I would never come up with it but for your comment.

Comment: That will create an array `sorted_arr` indexed from 1 to `legnth(arr)` whose values are the original indices of `arr` in a random order. I can't imagine what you'd do with such an array or how it relates to your question. I suspect you have some fundamental misunderstanding of how arrays work and are trying to do something simple in a very complicated way.

Comment: You made this question much more difficult to understand by not posting a [mcve] that addresses just the problem you wanted to solve. There was no need for a call to `patsplit()` and 2 separate arrays and all that complexity around `b[a[i]] = seps[i]` and `sum+=a[i]; arr[sum]=seps[i]` This could have been as simple as "I want to delete an element from the middle of an array and re-index it with contiguous numbers" with example `split("x y z",a); delete a[2]; do_something; for (i in a) print i, a[i]` giving expected output `1 x\n2 z` and ask how to write `do_something`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what was asked for in the question:

```
echo 5TOMATO3CUCUMBER4ORANGE | gawk '{

    n = patsplit($0, a, /[0-9]/, seps)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        sum+=a[i]
        arr[sum]=seps[i]
    }

for (i in arr)
    {print arr[i], "index", i}

asort(arr,sorted_arr,"@ind_num_asc")

for (i in sorted_arr)
    {print sorted_arr[i], "index", i}
}
'
TOMATO index 5
CUCUMBER index 8
ORANGE index 12
TOMATO index 1
CUCUMBER index 2
ORANGE index 3
```

It took [one of the OPs comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537765/replacing-indices-in-awk-array-while-keeping-the-order-of-values-unchanged/66563240?noredirect=1#comment117687574_66563240) for me to finally understand this question is simply asking how to add/delete indices to/from a numerically-indexed array and re-index it with sequential numbers starting from 1. That would be this, using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    n = split("a b c d e",arr)

    print "before:"
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print i, (i in arr ? "<" arr[i] ">" : "absent")
    }

    delete arr[2]
    delete arr[4]

    print "\nduring:"
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print i, (i in arr ? "<" arr[i] ">" : "absent")
    }

    c = 0
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if ( i in arr ) {
            arr[++c] = arr[i]
        }
    }
    for (i=c+1; i<=n; i++) {
        delete arr[i]
    }

    print "\nafter:"
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print i, (i in arr ? "<" arr[i] ">" : "absent")
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
before:
1 <a>
2 <b>
3 <c>
4 <d>
5 <e>

during:
1 <a>
2 absent
3 <c>
4 absent
5 <e>

after:
1 <a>
2 <c>
3 <e>
4 absent
5 absent
```

Alternatively if you have GNU awk for `asort()`, then you can do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    n = split("a b c d e",arr)

    print "before:"
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print i, (i in arr ? "<" arr[i] ">" : "absent")
    }

    delete arr[2]
    delete arr[4]

    print "\nduring:"
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print i, (i in arr ? "<" arr[i] ">" : "absent")
    }

    asort(arr,arr,"@ind_num_asc")

    print "\nafter:"
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print i, (i in arr ? "<" arr[i] ">" : "absent")
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
before:
1 <a>
2 <b>
3 <c>
4 <d>
5 <e>

during:
1 <a>
2 absent
3 <c>
4 absent
5 <e>

after:
1 <a>
2 <c>
3 <e>
4 absent
5 absent
```

---

Original answer and revisions:

This question still doesn't make sense.

When you say `I know that sorting by definition changes the order, but why it still does so with PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@unsorted"?` - there's nothing about that statement that changes the order of anything, what is it you think it's changing the order of and what do you base that on?

When you say `I want to changes them by assigning consecutive ordinals to values in each array`) - that is what you already have as the output of `patsplit()`.

When you say `My goal is to be able to get every n-th pair of elements from the arrays.` - just accessing arrays as `a[n]` and `seps[n]` gives you exactly that.

When you say `Importantly, I want to modify the array itself, not the output.` - modify which array to be what? Both arrays output by `patsplit()` seem to already be structured as you say you want.

When you say (in a comment) `I know how to do what I need with some twisted loops` - if you show us that code in your question it'd probably help us understand what it is you're trying to do.

Consider this code:

```
echo 5TOMATO3CUCUMBER4ORANGE | gawk '{
    n = patsplit($0, a, /[0-9]/, seps)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "index=%d\tseps[%d]=%s\ta[%d]=%s\n", i, i, seps[i], i, a[i]
    }
}'
index=1  seps[1]=TOMATO    a[1]=5
index=2  seps[2]=CUCUMBER  a[2]=3
index=3  seps[3]=ORANGE    a[3]=4
```

Update your question to show what you would want the output of that loop to be so you can clearly show us how you want the arrays structured in terms of indices and values that are different from the above and clearly explain what is wrong with that output and in what way the arrays need to be structured differently.

Edit 1: given your updated requirements, it sounds like this is what you want:

```
echo 5TOMATO3CUCUMBER4ORANGE | gawk '{
    n = patsplit($0, a, /[0-9]/, seps)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        a[i] = i
        printf "index=%d\tseps[%d]=%s\ta[%d]=%s\n", i, i, seps[i], i, a[i]
    }
}'
index=1  seps[1]=TOMATO    a[1]=1
index=2  seps[2]=CUCUMBER  a[2]=2
index=3  seps[3]=ORANGE    a[3]=3
```

but I can't imagine what the use case would be for that.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton for all your input, this is hugely helpful for me - an absolute beginner trying to write a script. I tried to distill my original example from my real script, but apparently reducing it to the minimum in this way obfuscated the purpose. I'll definitely do better next time, and I appreciate your time and patience! Will go through the question today and make it more transparent for the reader.

Comment: You're welcome. To be clear, the issue wasn't in reducing it to the minimum per-se, it was reducing your script to the least of that that included lines that demonstrated the problem instead of coming up with a brand new script that **only**demonstrates the problem. Reducing your script to create the example left unnecessary complications in  the example such as using `patsplit()` and having 2 arrays to deal and a complicated way of changing one of them when none of that was anything to do with the problem you were asking about and so just made the question much harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This produces your desired output:

```sh
echo 5TOMATO3CUCUMBER4ORANGE | gawk '{
    n = patsplit($0, a, /[0-9]/, seps)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print seps[i], a[i]
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print seps[i], i
}'
```

```
TOMATO 5
CUCUMBER 3
ORANGE 4
TOMATO 1
CUCUMBER 2
ORANGE 3
```

---

I'm not understanding what your end goal is: with sorting, you are changing the *meaning* of the indices between `b` and `sorted_b`:

```sh
echo 5TOMATO3CUCUMBER4ORANGE | gawk '{
  n = patsplit($0, a, /[0-9]/, seps)
  max = a[1]
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
     b[a[i]] = seps[i]
     if (a[i] > max) max = a[i]
  }
  n = asort(b, sorted_b)
  printf "%2s %-10s %-10s\n", "i","b","sorted_b"
  for (i=1; i<=max; i++)
      printf "%2s %-10s %-10s\n", i, b[i], sorted_b[i]
}'
```

```
 i b          sorted_b
 1            CUCUMBER
 2            ORANGE
 3 CUCUMBER   TOMATO
 4 ORANGE
 5 TOMATO
```

Comment: Indeed, but I'd like to have the array modified, to just the output. And I'm not surprised either, except that I set the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@unsorted"`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're surprised the indexes change when you sort the array: see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html

Comment: Are you looking for `asorti` instead?

Comment: No, it was the same problem. I know how to do what I need with some twisted loops, but I'm looking for a more efficient way if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gersh99, I found a solution (`"@unsorted"` parameter for `asort` function):

```
echo 5TOMATO3CUCUMBER4ORANGE | gawk '{

    n = patsplit($0, a, /[0-9]/, seps)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        sum+=a[i]
        arr[sum]=seps[i]
    }

for (i in arr)
    {print arr[i], "index", i}

asort(arr, sorted_arr, "@unsorted")

for (i in sorted_arr)
    {print sorted_arr[i], "index", i}
}
```

gives:

```
TOMATO index 5
CUCUMBER index 8
ORANGE index 12
TOMATO index 1
CUCUMBER index 2
ORANGE index 3
```

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. `asort(arr, sorted_arr, "@unsorted")` will populate `sorted_arr` in a random order and then `for (i in sorted_arr)` will access its values in a random order. If that combination of randomness-squared produced the specific order of output you wanted for this specific input using this specific awk on this specific platform it's just blind luck. Actually, it DOESN'T output the order you say you want in your question - `TOMATO index 1; ORANGE index 2; CUCUMBER index 3`!

Comment: Firstly, you are right, it was my typo. The values were supposed to be in the same order and the question is corrected now. Secondly, I wanted to keep the values in the same order, but to reassign indices. Imagine you have 10 bottles standing on the wall `(1-10)`, and two accidentally fall, let's say `3` and `7`. The rest stays in the original positions. Now, let's re-label the bottles by assigning numbers 1-8` while not moving moving any of the bottles. Isn't this equivalent scenario?

Comment: OK, NOW I understand. What you are currently doing in this answer does not do that. Please update your question to say THAT and to show an example where you're deleting 2 entries from 1 or both arrays and what you want both arrays (or 1 if you're only interested in 1) to look like after the deletion.